# Proof of the Cardinality of the power set of $\Bbb Q$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proof of the Cardinality of the power set of $\Bbb Q$, i realize the continuum hypotheses if taken says there no cardinality between $|\Bbb N|$ and $|\Bbb R $ i also know that the cardinality of a power set is strictly larger than than the cardinality of the original set. I am assuming this means that it ends up being that the cardinality of the power set of any countable infinite set is the same as the cardinality of $\Bbb R$. Is there a nice map that shows this?

Comment: Your second-to-last sentence isn't what you intended, I think: $\mathbb{R}$ isn't countable, so of course the cardinality of a countable infinite set is *not* the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, I've removed the "large cardinals" tag - it refers to [a very different topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal).

Comment: @NoahSchweber yeah i clearly mean to add "of the power set" edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you meant to ask whether - assuming $\mathsf{CH}$ - $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as **the powerset of** any countably infinite set.

The answer is yes, and in fact this has nothing to do with $\mathsf{CH}$. The points are these:

- Without $\mathsf{CH}$ we can show $\vert\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$.
- Also without $\mathsf{CH}$ we can show that the powerset operation **preserves equicardinality**. Suppose $\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a bijection, and consider the map $$g:\mathcal{P}(A)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(B): X\mapsto \{f(x): x\in X\}.$$ It's a good exercise to show that $g$ is also a bijection. So if two sets have the same cardinality (e.g. if they're both countably infinite) then their powersets also have the same cardinality.

As a particular consequence, if $A$ is countably infinite then $\vert A\vert=\vert\mathbb{N}\vert$ and so $\vert\mathcal{P}(A)\vert=\vert\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$. And again, none of the above involves $\mathsf{CH}$.

Comment: Is $X=\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur No, $X$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$. The notation $$h: U\rightarrow V: u\mapsto v$$  (with $v$ an expression involving $u$) means "$h$ is a function from $U$ to $V$, which sends each $u$ to the corresponding $v$." Note the difference in the arrows, "$\rightarrow$" ("\rightarrow") versus "$\mapsto$" ("\mapsto"). See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936558/use-of-mapsto-and-to).

Comment: I didn't notice that you had the mapsto arrow and thought that is was just to.